# Plupload get file name after upload serverside

Tags: php, file, upload, plupload

I'm using PLUPLOAD to upload files to my webpage.
However, I would like to get the names of the files that I uplodaed. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780773/plupload-upload-filename-issues

Comment: There's no working solution there, unfortunately :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<strike>You never said what code you are using so I will just give you a solutin in .NET VB using a generic handler.</strike>

Sorry did not notice the `php` tag, but here it is anyway in in .NET

**upload.ashx**

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

Dim fileName as String = If(context.Request("name") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("name"), String.Empty)

end sub
```

**plupload.aspx**

Just initialise pluploader as per Manual with out setting unique_names, pluolpader sends the filename, chunk and chunks with each POST.

---

**upload.php**

So in PHP i think it should be.. ( I am not PHP guy but here you go)

```
$_POST["name"];
```

-or-

```
$_REQUEST["name"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use .NET, and I can't program in it, is there any PHP way? :/

Comment: `$_POST["name"];`  should be a pretttttty good hint.. This code is very simple 3 lines.. its right there